# Can I git rebase and specify merge strategy per file ahead of time?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'd like to do a `git rebase` where I specify for some files that the strategy is `ours` and the remaining files use the default strategy.

Is there a way to accomplish this? How?

Comment: The short answer is no; the long answer is "sort of, through merge drivers, but it's a pain and doesn't work for all cases anyway so you are probably better off doing this some other way." Also, if you start down this path, remember that during a rebase, "ours" means the upstream and "theirs" means your commits!

Comment: @torek I'm interested in other options which I could script to have the same effect. For CI reasons, there is one local file which will always have a conflict and our protocol will always be to choose the local file. I'll accept an answer that accomplishes what I need without user intervention.

Comment: If you're *guaranteed* to have a merge conflict on every step of a rebase, you can use the merge driver approach. Otherwise (if you have no changes but they do), you may pick up unwanted changes. Usually you hit this kind of problem with a configuration file, and the usual solution is to *not* source-control that file at all: instead, source-control a template from which the actual config is generated once when needed, then left alone (via `.gitignore` and not being in the repo).